# How do I get my table contents to scroll, the table structure stays fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I need to scroll my table contents horizontally but the table structure should stay fixed. How can I do this? In my code,it scrolls with the table structure. in that case, the corner radius only visible in both the ends. I need to make the background structure fixed and the content scroll horizontally. I need the output like the below image.
[image: I need the output like this]

```css
table {
  width: 120%;
}

td {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.scrollsec {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

th {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

th:nth-child(1) {
  border-radius: 11px 0px 0px 9px;
}

th:nth-last-child(1) {
  border-radius: 0px 11px 9px 0px;
}

.bodySec {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.he20 {
  height: 20px;
}

.bodySec tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) {
  border-radius: 11px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.bodySec tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-last-child(1) {
  border-radius: 0px 9px 0px 0px;
}

.bodySec tr:nth-last-child(1) td:nth-last-child(1) {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 11px 0px;
}

.bodySec tr:nth-last-child(1) td:nth-child(1) {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 11px;
}

.scrollsec::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12  scrollsec">
  <table>
    <thead class='tableHeadSec'>
      <tr>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
      </tr>

    </thead>
    <tr class='he20'></tr>
    <tbody class='bodySec'>
      <tr>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


</div>
```

Comment: code - https://jsfiddle.net/user94/kn9fhL4x/6/

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

thead {
  display: table; 
  width: calc(100% - 15px); 
}

tbody {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px; 
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

th, td {
   
  padding: 5px;
  word-break: break-all; 
}

tr {
  display: table; 
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
 <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
      </tr>

    </thead>
   
    <tbody >
      <tr>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

css:

```
  table {
      width: 100%;
    }

    table, td {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    thead {
      display: table; 
      width: calc(100% - 15px); 
    }

    tbody {
      display: block;
      max-height: 200px; 
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    th, td {

      padding: 5px;
      word-break: break-all; 
    }

    tr {
      display: table; 
      width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box; 
    }

    td {
      text-align: center;
      border-bottom: none;
      border-left: none;
    }
```

Html:

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
      </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody >
      <tr>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>
        <td>Transaction Id</td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I hope this this i may help you.Its just example data.

Comment: I need a scroll horizontally. and the structure will remain fixed.

Comment: Actually what you need?Do you want scroll on the top of the table.

Comment: Did you need these type of design.

Comment: this is my working code. in that case when i scroll the table structure also scrolls. i can see the border-radius only in both the ends. i need to make that outline fixed and the content should scroll horizontally.

Comment: You need fixed table but tbody should be scroll on

Comment: tbody section and thead section should scroll horizontally. but i need to keep the corner radius fixed while scrolling.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. actually I need a horizontal scroll with a fixed structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this solution:

https://codepen.io/Khadembd/pen/GRKOaVj

```css
body{
  font-family:arial;
}

table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width:900px;
}

thead tr th, tbody tr td{
  text-align:left;
  padding:10px 15px;
  width:300px;
}

thead tr th{
  background-color:#333;
  color:#fff;
}

.tbody{
  display: block;
  height:200px;
  overflow-y:auto;
}

tbody tr td{
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Phone Number</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<table class="tbody">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>john@gmail.com</td>
      <td>123456789</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>john@gmail.com</td>
      <td>123456789</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>john@gmail.com</td>
      <td>123456789</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>john@gmail.com</td>
      <td>123456789</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>john@gmail.com</td>
      <td>123456789</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>john@gmail.com</td>
      <td>123456789</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>john@gmail.com</td>
      <td>123456789</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>john@gmail.com</td>
      <td>123456789</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>john@gmail.com</td>
      <td>123456789</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>john@gmail.com</td>
      <td>123456789</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>john@gmail.com</td>
      <td>123456789</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>john@gmail.com</td>
      <td>123456789</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```